# How to remove/increase execution timeout of the geth's evm?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-invocation, evm, benchmark

I am performing some benchmarking with the Ethereum Virtual Machine. I have a contract with just one function that calculates the prime numbers until 100k. However, I am not able to get my results as the execution in geth is limited to 5 seconds. When I try to perform a call, I get the following error:

`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":68,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"execution aborted (timeout = 5s)"}}`

The gas limit is not a problem here, I increased it (in the genesis block) to a large enough value so it would not impact the execution. I initialized geth with the following command:

`geth --datadir=./data/ --networkid 68 --rpc.gascap 100000000000 --http --allow-insecure-unlock  console`

I thought the problem might be their VM so I tried using a different instance of the EVM called [evmone](https://github.com/ethereum/evmone) using the --vm-evm option, but it didn't help with anything. Also, geth does not provide any command-line options to set the timeout. There are --metric options though, but I do not think they have any relation.

I just need to increase the timeout limit to a large enough value in order to perform my experiments. I hope this limitation is not hard-coded and there is some solution.

Can you help?

Answer (score 4):

Ran into the same problem. [Looking at the code](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/d60cfd2604a4615078696da20d474828be65ab70/internal/ethapi/api.go#L975), there seems to be a hardcoded timeout to 5 seconds.

Comment: Not sure, what revision you pointed at, but as of https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/d60cfd2604a4615078696da20d474828be65ab70/internal/ethapi/api.go#L883 it seems to come in a parameter.
Now Where does the value come from?

Comment: @Huge I edited the link using a branch. If you see where the function was called from you'll end up with a hardcoded 5*time.Second further up the stack ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can run geth with the --rpc.evmtimeout flag to change the 5s timeout. If you set it to 0 , then timeout will be infinite. Check geth --help for more info.